# Using spinwheel gets: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to add a spinwheel command in my economy system but it is giving the error again and again:
`(TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str')`.
This is the code -

```
@bot.command()
async def spinwheel(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    a = "lost", "win", "lost", "win", "lost"
    b = random.choice(a)
    c ="100" , "0" ,"200" ,"50" , "75", "130", "17" ,"1000"
    earnings = random.choice(c)
    
    if b == "win":
        await ctx.send(f"luckily you got a ticket and got {earnings} coins")
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

        with open("mainbank.json",'w') as f:
            json.dump(users,f)

    else:
        em = discord.Embed(title = "spinwheel", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(random.randrange(0 , 255) , random.randrange(0 , 255) , random.randrange(0 , 255)))

        em.add_field(name = "BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME", value = "Tickets ran out. Till then you could see the prize list by clicking on the thumbnail")

        em.set_thumbnail(url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/853248452095115315/853248524146049064/spinwheel_command_prize_list.png")

        await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Comment: You can't concatenate string with int. You need to convert the string to int.

Comment: `c ="100" , "0" ,"200" ,"50" , "75", "130", "17" ,"1000"` -> `c =100 , 0 ,200 ,50 , 75, 130, 17 ,1000`

Comment: Why are `c` all strings‽ Make them ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list `c` is `string` type so either you can make it int or else typecast your variable `earnings` to `int` type